# обьясните код за иницилизацией класса в примере boost.asio

Tags: c++

код из примера http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp

```
class client
{
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
  const std::string& server, const std::string& path)
: resolver_(io_service),        //в чем смысл оператора ":" ???
  socket_(io_service)
{
 ...
 ...

 }}
```

как взаимодействуют иницилизация класса и процедуры за ними? в чем смысл оператора ":" в том месте?

Comment: В данном случе - это блок инициализации. Надеюсь, старички стека вам подробно распишут... А лучше, почитать это самостоятельно в умных книжках. Да, вопрос не относится к бусту, и асио. Уберите их из тегов.

Comment: >>иницилизация класса и процедуры за ними<< сразу не заметил. В блоке инициализации, в данном коде, вызывается два конструктора, то есть, инициализируются переменные resolver_ и socket_.